# Bus error 10 / Library not loaded error with PCL and cmake

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake, point-cloud-library

I'm using the point cloud library and tried to downsample a point cloud using a voxel grid. It worked fine when I was using Xcode, where I manually added the required libraries, but not with cmake. The program compiles fine with cmake but if I run the program compiled by cmake I get the following error:

```
$ ./main
$ Bus error: 10
```

I figured out that the error only occurs when `pcl/filters/voxel_grid.h` is included. I used other classes of PCL in the program before and everything worked fine with cmake.

If also figured out that if `pcl/filters/voxel_grid.h` is included and I remove `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")` from my cmake file the program will compile and run fine just like it did in Xcode(language dialect in Xcode is set to C++11). The problem is, I need c++11 features and also cmake since I need to be able to easily build the program on a different OS.

I'm on OS X 10.9.2 and using clang 3.4, boost 1.55.0, PCL 1.7.1 and CUDA 5.5.

It would be great if someone could help me.

Thanks for your help

Here is a minimal example:

```
//main.cpp

#include <pcl/filters/voxel_grid.h> // it works if this include is removed

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

The cmake file I use:

```
#cmake file

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)
project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

find_package(PCL 1.7 REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost 1.55 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main ${PCL_LIBRARIES} ${BOOST_LIBRARIES})
```

### Solution/Error cause

I found the root cause of the problem. I compiled an example what causes the same problem manually on the console so that I could compare the different compiler flags/settings used by Xcode and cmake.

What I found out is, that Xcode adds some flags that cmake doesn't add. One of the flags/options Xcode adds is "-fvisibility-inlines-hidden". With that option set the example program compiles and runs fine, without the option set it compiles but generates a "Bus error: 10"  at runtime.

It would be great if some could explain what that option does and why it's necessary when compiling. Is this just clang or OS X specific, so that on a different OS/compiler the option isn't needed?

Regards and thanks, 
Ruediger

Comment: Wow yes I got exactly the same problem after a PCL git update and rebuild - would never have working this out in a million years without your help. No idea why it happens though!